# Get distinct output from an array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

From a string array

```
string[] str1={"u1-u2","u1-u2","u1-u4","u4-u1"};
string[] str2 = str1.Distinct().ToArray();
```

Distinct elements in a arry is:`"u1-u2"`,`"u1-u4"`,`"u4-u1"`

But i have to get distinct output like this: `"u1-u2"`,`"u1-u4"`.

so please help me out

Comment: Why exactly does the output have to look like that? Are the pairs unordered (so x-y is always the same as y-x)?

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
string[] output = str1.Select(s => new { Value = s, NormalizedValue = string.Join("-", s.Split('-').OrderBy(_ => _)) })
                      .GroupBy(p => p.NormalizedValue)
                      .Select(g => g.OrderBy(p => p.Value).First().Value)
                      .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert all values to their normalized form and the call `Distinct()` on that:

```
string[] output = str1.Select(string.Join("-", s.Split('-').OrderBy(x => x)))
                      .Distinct()
                      .ToArray();
```

(This is based on the code from [Ulugbek Umirov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23149913/41071).)

Comment: I did like that in first version of answer, but it causes the following problem: `{"u4-u1"}` => `{"u1-u4"}`.

Comment: If you consider u4-u1 and u1-u4 to be equal, then you also shouldn't care which one is going to be in the output. But the problem certainly isn't specified well enough to know that for sure.

Comment: Yes, but it's rather strange to see in output the value you don't have in the input.